# Передача координат в Яндекс карты в модальном окне

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, яндекс-карты

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Mars14/f8Lwac9q/185)

Пытаюсь передать координаты в модальное окно (для центрирования карты), но, похоже что координаты не считываются в jQuery и, соответственно, карта не центрируется.
Возможно, что-то не так с последовательностью выполнения шагов и открытия карты...

```
 ymaps.ready(init);
            
            var lat1 = 55;
            var long1 = 37;
            
            var lat = 55.8;
                    var long = 37.7;
 function init ()
 {  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map',
        {   center: [lat, long],
            zoom: 9,
            controls: ["zoomControl", "fullscreenControl"]
        });
        
        myMap.setCenter([lat1, long1], 9, {
    checkZoomRange: true
        });
 }
 
 
 
 
 $('#orderModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var lat2 = $(event.relatedTarget).data('LA');
  var long2 = $(event.relatedTarget).data('LO');
  
  
  myMap.setCenter([lat2, long2], 9, {
    checkZoomRange: true
        });
});
```

Comment: в приведенном фрагменте кода в 3 раза задаете координаты центра. одного не достаточно?

Comment: Фрагмент рабочий, т.е. в разработке. Это не окончательный вариант, в котором хотелось бы в первом же цикле отцентрировать по полученным координатам.

Comment: чтобы координаты откуда то считывались, нужно чтобы они туда записывались. Из приведенного не ясно записываются они туда или нет. В целом проверить считываются они ли нет не должно составлять сложностей, выведите в консоль что считали и посмотрите.

Comment: Андрей Терехов, как раз для такой проверки и используется одна из пар координат. Уже проверено  - не приходят (не считываются). Также, если у вас нет конкретики по данному вопросу, прошу не пишите в комментариях общую информацию и ваши поверхностные замечания. Ваши остроты держите, пожалуйста, при себе.

Comment: вам тут вроде вопрос решить помогают, а вы дерзить начинаете. Мои поверхностные замечания должны очевидно приводить к простой цепочке - проверить полученные координаты, если их нет, проверить откуда они берутся. И вот неожиданность,  `event.relatedTarget` появился лишь в бутстрапе 3, а у вас 2.3. Более того, относительно оформления вопроса, сниппет можно было вставить прямо в вопрос, или привести к нему верстку. Или хотя бы текстом ссылку нормально обозначить, чтобы ее заметно было нормально.

Comment: Если бы вы еще и консоль в целом открывали, то  заметили бы там ругать на переменную `myMap` которая не в области видимости

Comment: Андрей Терехов, то, как вы пишете - это не похоже на помощь. Скорее похоже на самохвальство. Я наверное должен поблагодарить за советы. Но, повторюсь, не надо писать советы типа потыкать там-сям и может что-то произойдёт. Флудить не надо. Если есть предложение по решению - пожалуйста, пишите. Пока от вас ничего дельного и существенного не исходит. В остальном - научитесь общаться, вникайте в вопрос. В общем, поднимайте свой культурный уровень.

Comment: я вам конкретный совет написал,даже два. первый - изменить зону видимости переменной карты. второй - event.relatedTarget не определено в используемой версии бутстрапа, очевидно получить координату оттуда не получится. Используйте другие способы для передачи параметров, либо через внешние переменные, либо открывайте окно руками сразу центрируя, либо помечайте кликнутую ссылку каким либо образом, чтобы знать, откуда брать данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем выуживать данные из связанных элементов, когда можно слушать их клик напрямую?

Исправьте **span id** и **span_id** на **class** и повесьте на их клик изменение переменных и **setCenter**.

```
$('.Map-txt').on('click', function (event) {
    lat = event.target.dataset.la;
    long = event.target.dataset.lo;
    myMap.setCenter([lat, long], 10, {
        checkZoomRange: true
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7r0ugy1/

Comment: Огромное спасибо!